# Random red pixels on screen

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I have a laptop with GeForce 970M graphics card (+integrated Intel HD Graphics).

I was playing big battle in StarCraft 2 (high cpu/gpu load) when some random red pixels appeared (external monitor). I thought it was game bug or something, so I switched to Windows 10 desktop - but red pixels did not disappeared.

Here some pictures:

[StarCraft 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eawHW.jpg)

[Windiows 10 desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81AzX.jpg)

I have restarted my computer, and run game again. After 5 minutes it happen again.

So I turned off laptop, cleaned fans, replugged hdmi cable, updated graphics card driver. Also next day I launched GPU stress test application and everything was fine (100% gpu load at 85^C). Cannot reproduce it again.

I know it is hard to diagnose, but maybe you recognize this red pixels pattern? Is my graphics card dying?:/

Comment: It could very well be your graphics card overheating. Laptops do not have adequate cooling and as such overheating may occur, and can produce weird artifacts on your screen like that. I would say roll back the drivers maybe to 1 older than the one you had before you updated. See if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it again, then as it was said it was overheating that fixed when you cleaned fan.